# SQL:How to get min Quantity?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this problem. When i tried to summarize the min quatity of nations's products and it did not work.
I have 2 tables below
PRODUCT:

```
ID|NAME |NaID|Qty
-------------------
01|Fruit|JP  |50
02|MEAT |AUS |10
03|MANGA|JP  |80
04|BOOK |AUS |8
```

NATION:

```
NaID |NAME 
-------------------
AUS  |Australia 
JP   |Japan
```

I want my result like this:

```
ID|NAME |Name|minQty
-------------------
01|Fruit|JP  |50     
04|BOOK |AUS |8
```

and i used:

```
select p.id,p.name, p.NaID,n.name,min(P.Qty)as minQty
from Product p,Nation n
where p.NaID=n.NaID
group by p.id,p.name, p.NaID,n.name,p.Qty
```

and i got this (T_T):

```
ID|NAME |NaID|minQty
-------------------
01|Fruit|JP  |50
02|MEAT |AUS |10
03|MANGA|JP  |80
04|BOOK |AUS |8
```

Please,Could soneone help me? I am thinking that i am bad at SQL now.

Comment: Which DBMS are you really using? You tagged your question with many different ones and the answer could depend on the features available in each.

Comment: remove p.Qty from group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 supports window functions, so you can do something like this:

```
select id,
       name, 
       NaID,
       name, 
       qty
from  (
  select p.id,
         p.name, 
         p.NaID,
         n.name,
         min(P.Qty) over (partition by n.naid) as min_qty, 
         p.qty
  from Product p
     join Nation n on p.NaID=n.NaID
) t
where qty = min_qty;
```

If there is more than one nation with the same minimum value, you will get each of them. If you don't want that, you need to use `row_number()`

```
select id,
       name, 
       NaID,
       name, 
       qty
from  (
  select p.id,
         p.name, 
         p.NaID,
         n.name,
         row_number() over (partition by n.naid order by p.qty) as rn, 
         p.qty
  from Product p
     join Nation n on p.NaID = n.NaID
) t
where rn = 1;
```

As your example output with only includes the NaID but not the nation's name you don't really need the the join between `product` and `nation`.

---

<sup>(There is no DBMS product called "SQL 2005". `SQL` is just a (standard) for a query language. The DBMS product you mean is called Microsoft SQL **Server** 2005. Or just SQL Server 2005)</sup>.

Comment: I DID IT with  below query:
select pid,
       pname, 
       pname, 
       min_qty
from  (
  select p.id as pid,
         p.name as pname, 
         n.name as nname,
         min(P.Qty) over (partition by n.naid) as min_qty, 
         p.qty
  from Product p
     join Nation n on p.NaID=n.NaID
) t
where qty = min_qty;

Comment: Sorry but i dunno how to answer properly in this forum

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use several techniques. You can use subqueries and analytic functions, but the most efficient one is to use aggregate functions [MIN](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions111.htm#SQLRF00667) and [FIRST](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions073.htm#SQLRF00641).

Your tables:

```
SQL> create table nation (naid,name)
  2  as
  3  select 'AUS', 'Australia' from dual union all
  4  select 'JP', 'Japan' from dual
  5  /

Table created.

SQL> create table product (id,name,naid,qty)
  2  as
  3  select '01', 'Fruit', 'JP', 50 from dual union all
  4  select '02', 'MEAT', 'AUS', 10 from dual union all
  5  select '03', 'MANGA', 'JP', 80 from dual union all
  6  select '04', 'BOOK', 'AUS', 8 from dual
  7  /

Table created.
```

The query:

```
SQL> select max(p.id) keep (dense_rank first order by p.qty) id
  2       , max(p.name) keep (dense_rank first order by p.qty) name
  3       , p.naid "NaID"
  4       , n.name "Nation"
  5       , min(p.qty) "minQty"
  6    from product p
  7         inner join nation n on (p.naid = n.naid)
  8   group by p.naid
  9       , n.name
 10  /

ID NAME  NaID Nation        minQty
-- ----- ---- --------- ----------
01 Fruit JP   Japan             50
04 BOOK  AUS  Australia          8

2 rows selected.
```

Since you're not using Oracle, a less efficient query, but probably working in all RDBMS:

```
SQL> select p.id
  2       , p.name
  3       , p.naid
  4       , n.name
  5       , p.qty
  6    from product p
  7         inner join nation n on (p.naid = n.naid)
  8   where ( p.naid, p.qty )
  9         in
 10         ( select p2.naid
 11                , min(p2.qty)
 12             from product p2
 13            group by p2.naid
 14         )
 15  /

ID NAME  NAID NAME             QTY
-- ----- ---- --------- ----------
01 Fruit JP   Japan             50
04 BOOK  AUS  Australia          8

2 rows selected.
```

Note that if you have several rows with the same minimum quantity per nation, all those rows will be returned, instead of just one as in the previous "Oracle"-query.

Comment: Sorry , my DB is SQL2005. But i will try it with dense_rank. Thank alot. I am still not sure about it but i think it would work.

Comment: SORRY, i am newbie SQL. Could u please Help me with SQL2005?

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
   select *,
      row_number() over (partition by Nation order by qty) as [rn]
   from product
)
select * from cte where [rn] = 1
```